# How to run method inside python file in google collab?

Tags: python, git, file, import

I am currently cloning a .py file from github and I want to use a method inside it.

Cloning was succesfull but I can not reach the file and method inside it. I tried import fileName but it's not working.

[image: The error message and file directory]

Comment: That file needs to be in the same directory as your calling module.  Do you know where the calling module lives?  Some of the IDEs make that difficult to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone` will create a folder named the same as the Gist, in this case `3b6a91cefb2f5c3098ed`. You can add that to the path like below. (However, there seems to be a bug in the module - or there is something I do not understand related to the module).

```py
!git clone https://gist.github.com/3b6a91cefb2f5c3098ed.git
import sys 
sys.path.append("3b6a91cefb2f5c3098ed")
import playmidi
```

Comment: The error that I got might be related to this module written for Python 2 and I was testing in Python 3